# Highlighting the entire label area in rectangular on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69d9tj95/) .I want to highlight the entire row of the parent for the drop down. Suppose in this scenario `level1` and `level23` should get highlighted as it is getting highlighted for the child items. I want to highlight the entire row with whole width. If it is the last child, I want to have bullet next to it. So, for the parent I want to highlight the entire row and for the child which doesn't have any further should have just square bullet next to it. Can someone please help me with these two things? As I am new to web UI technologies, I hardly got up to this working which took so much time. If someone could please help, would be appreciated.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="well">
              <div>
                  <ul class="nav">
                      <li>
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><label label-default="" class="tree-toggle nav-header">Level1</label>
                          <ul class="nav tree" style="display: none;">
                              <li><a href="">Level21</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="">Level22</a>
                              </li>

                              <li>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><label label-default="" class="tree-toggle nav-header">Level23</label>
                            <ul class="nav tree" style="display: none;">
                              <li><a href="">Level31</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="">Level32</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>

                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the full width background color it looks like you will need to add some additional html. Basically I would add a div around level1 and level23 like so:

```
<div class="header-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><label label-default="" class="tree-toggle nav-header">Level1</label></div>
```

You will then need to add some extra CSS:

```
 .nav > li > .header-row:hover,
nav > li > .header-row:active{
 text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000;   
}
```

and adjust your toggle JS:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
```

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wshm6d5n/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to have the highlighting of same height because it is with less height when compared to child item, should that be hardcoded in the css that you added? One more thing is can we get the bullets next to child items which don't have any further child?

Comment: Yeah just add css padding to the div I added: .header-row{
 padding:5px 0px;   
}

Comment: In your case with bullets I would just add an HTML image for a small bullet of your choice inside the <a href="">Level21</a> tag or you could add a background image to the <a href="">Level21</a> for the bullet which would require you to add a class to each LI without further children. You could add list style to those list items with a class but they would be outside your highlighted background and would not look too good.

Comment: No, I upvoted because I waited for the second answer for bullets. Anyways I was away so now I will do, thanks.